# Exporting folders from a Dir to Text doc. Spacing issues

Tags: batch-file

I am trying to export a list of folders using the dir command.  The problem I am having is whenever I try to export a dir that contains spaces or some other special char like ().

I would like to keep the code in this format.

```
ECHO OFF & setLocal EnableDELAYedExpansion


REM Works!
for /d %%a in ("C:\Windows\Boot") do dir /a:D /on /b "%%a" > dork.TXT


REM Empty Text Doc
for /d %%a in ("C:\Program Files (x86)") do dir /a:D /on /b "%%a" > dork1.TXT


REM Empty Text Doc
for /d %%a in ("C:\Program Files") do dir /a:D /on /b "%%a" > dork2.TXT


REM Empty Text Doc
for /d %%a in (C:\Program Files) do dir /a:D /on /b "%%a" > dork3.TXT


REM kills Batch in its tracks
for /d %%a in (C:\Program Files (x86)) do dir /a:D /on /b "%%a" > dork4.TXT
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try like this :

```
@echo off
(for /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir /a:D /on /b "C:\Program Files (x86)"') do echo %%a)>dork1.TXT
```

Comment: You are the Grand master!  What was I doing wrong?  I am looking over it right now trying to figure that out.

Comment: Yup, I have no idea why that works.  But I have not been doing this for long.  Thanks for the help!  I will play around with what you gave me and see how it works.  Thank you very much again.

Answer (score 0):

read `HELP FOR`, and try this command in the command line

```
for /D %a in ("c:\windows\boot\*") do @echo %~nxa
```

it iterates over all the directories (`/D`) and echoes the name and extension (`%~nx`) of the found files (`%a`)

then, to iterate over all your directories, try

```
for %a in ("C:\Windows\Boot" "C:\Program Files (x86)" "C:\Program Files") do @for /d %b in ("%~a\*") do @echo %b
```

and finally, change the syntax to adapt to a bat file

```
for %%a in ("C:\Windows\Boot" "C:\Program Files (x86)" "C:\Program Files") do (
  for /d %%b in ("%%~a\*") do (
    echo %%b
  )
)
```

and redirect the output as needed.